# Why does document.evaluate('.', document.body, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue throw an exception?

Tags: dom, xpath, document.evaluate

If I tell the XPath evaluator that I want a `XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE` (8) instead, or `ANY_UNORDERED_NODE_TYPE` (9), I get the `body` element, as expected – but all other result types yield a `The expression cannot be converted to return the specified type.` exception (in Firefox; WebKit and Opera seem less generous, settling for just naming it `TYPE_ERR: DOM XPath Exception 52` instead.

What is going on? And, to rephrase the question for clarity: why is selecting the context node a type error, instead of clearly inferred as a single-node result, which is obvious from the XPath expression itself (`"."`, a synonym to `"self::node()"`), at least to myself as a human?

(For reference, it is not accessing `.singleNodeValue` specifically that triggers the error – all the XPathResult's properties are indicative of this same error.)

Answer (score 2):

Well there is a spec http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-XPath/xpath.html#XPathResult-singleNodeValue which clearly says about `singleNodeValue` that a "TYPE_ERR (is) raised if resultType is not ANY_UNORDERED_NODE_TYPE or FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE.". The implementations follow that spec.